# Small error on claim.py def load():

Tags: python

I am having a load error on my claim.py when i reload claim.DB on my bot. This is the code:

```
def load():
    claimDB = {}
    data = open("claim.DB").read().split("\n")
    for a in data:
       if a.strip() != "":
          claimDB[a.split(",")[0]] = a.split(",")[1:]
    claim.claimDB = claimDB
```

After it reloads it causes this:
    {'charles': []}  This is the correct way it should be.

To turn into this after the reload:
    {'charles': ['']} This is not the correct way.

Which it's not suppose to do. I'm not really sure how to fix it so that doesn't happen.

Comment: What is it supposed to do then?

Comment: It's suppose to keep the dict to {'charles': []}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the claimDB is a list:

```
def load():
    claimDB = {}
    data = open("claim.DB").read().split("\n")
    for a in data:
       aslist = a.split(",")
       if len(aslist) ==  0:
          pass # Blank Line so skip
       else
          claimDB[data[0]] = [a.strip() for a in data[1:] if len(a)]
```

# Claim(s) N.B. if aslist = ['something',] then aslist[1:] = []

```
    claim.claimDB = claimDB
```

Of course if your claimDB is only access through your code you could save all the trouble reading & writing it by changing save and load to:

```
import pickle

def save(claim):
   """ Save between sessions """
   with outfile = open('saveclaims.db' 'wb'):
      pickle.dump(outfile, claim.claimDB)
   finally:
      outfile.flush()
      outfile.close()

def load(claim):
   """ Load saved between sessions """
   with infile = open('saveclaims.db' 'rb'):
      claim.claimDB = pickle.dump(infile)
   finally:
      infile.close()
```

Comment: Its a list yeah :P when it adds on the code is claim.claimDB[user] = claim.claimDB[user]+[name]

Comment: Ah I never used the pickle module before. But that actually looks a lot easier to do.

Comment: It is a lot more flexible and it is worth learning pickle in any case.

Comment: Yeah. I've heard about that module but never got a chance to try it out. I should try learning it.

Comment: Uh should I keep the if a.strip() != "": in the code for def load():?

Comment: Nope still not working. It's still causing the dict to do {'charles': ['']}

Comment: Fixed the use case with trialling comma and added `strip()` to remove leading and trailing spaces

Answer (score 1):

That happens when you have trailing commas. That is, if your "claim.DB" file contains something like this:

```
charles,
```

One way to resolve this is to strip the trailing commas like this:

```
def load():
    claimDB = {}
    data = open("claim.DB").read().split("\n")
    for a in data:
       a = a.strip(', \n\t')
       if a != "":
          claimDB[a.split(",")[0]] = a.split(",")[1:]
    claim.claimDB = claimDB
```

Comment: Nice I will try that. Thanks<3

Comment: The way it looks with more names in the [] is like a list {'charles': ['test', 'name', 'tim']} like that :P